# How to keep an infinite loop running in order to not close a container in docker

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

I want to keep a docker container running even after executing the run command (containers exit immediately after `docker run..`. I know the command:

```
  while :;do 
   sleep 300
  done
```

during `docker run` will make it run but how do I edit the  **Dockerfile**  itself in order to keep it running?

Comment: Why not just daemonize it?

Answer (score 14):

You can do this by putting the commands you want to execute into a script, and setting the script to be the command Docker runs when it starts a container:

```
FROM sixeyed/ubuntu-with-utils

RUN echo 'ping localhost &' > /bootstrap.sh
RUN echo 'sleep infinity' >> /bootstrap.sh
RUN chmod +x /bootstrap.sh

CMD /bootstrap.sh
```

When you build an image from this Dockerfile and run a container from the image, it will start `ping` in the background and `sleep` in the foreground, so you can daemonize the container with `docker run -d` and it will keep running.

This is not ideal though - Docker only monitors the last process it started when it ran the container, so it will be checking on `sleep` rather than `ping`. If the `ping` command errors the container will keep running. Typically, you want the real application to be the only thing you start in the `CMD`.